# What happen when SQL Server AG failover?

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014

While analyzing Dynamic Management Views captured against fail-over server, observed that DMV is getting flush or SQL Engine going to reset the statistics.
In the production environment, it is not allowed to flush/clear the DMV, based on this I am identifying the delta between them. While calculating the delta I come to know that many times previous value is greater than current value.
My question is, let say if database A is configured in AG1 with 2 server like primary-secondary, while switching from primary to secondary will it be going to reset the primary server stats  and what are the different reasons that could cause for DMV is getting reset?
Also what happens in the recompilation case for that particular procedure is it going to reset the DMV stats ?

Comment: Could you please share with us what are the DMVs that are getting flush and that you need to retain their information? When you say failover are you talking about a SQL Azure Database Geo-replication scenario? I would like to test myself and share all findings with Microsoft SQL Azure team, and try to get a feedback that I can share with you.

Comment: Its in on-premise servers, its procedure statistics capture from DMV "sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats".

Comment: I do not have access to SQL Server team, I saw tag azure-sql-database and thought your were referring to Azure SQL Database, Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the failover occurs, you're moving from one server to another server. Sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats is providing information about procedures that are currently in cache. Since you changed servers, there is nothing in cache for that database after the failover. Therefore, you're going to see radical differences from one server to another after a failover.

It's not a reset of the information. It's simply that the information in the procedure cache of one server is not the same as the information in the procedure cache of another server.

Comment: I am agree on the points you mentioned, however i have did consideration of Primary and secondary server, and capturing DMV respectively and getting delta with respective server, but i am curious to know the different reasons could reset DMV stats during fail-over.

Comment: I am identifying that when the previous value of DMV is greater than current capture value then i am considering that DMV got reset during that time-period.

Comment: If a query is called three times in the morning and four times in the afternoon and a failover occurs between the two, you'll see higher values after the failover. Because the values in sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats are cache dependent, anything that causes changes in cache will change those values. It's not like the Query Store where all values are stored.

Comment: If a plan ages out of cache you'll see it go. If statistics get updated and the plan recompiles, you'll see the stats change. Structural changes. Reboots. Failovers. Taking the database offline. Clearing cache using dbcc freeproccache. All these can affect what is in cache.

Comment: thank you so much, its more informative and knowledgeable.